# syntax error when i include use "distinct"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have try to include this code to my program, but the number show in dashboard not match with the database (mysql) should be "4" in my dashboard You can see my picture. this  is my code :

```
<?php echo $this->db->query("SELECT count( distinct destination_name_) FROM mobil")->num_rows(); ?>
```

my colum in table name  : destination_name
my database name        : mobil

please help me,
thk u before

[image: this is my code screenshot,table,and my dashboard]

Comment: instead of screenshot of code put code in question.

Comment: you should print the result not the num_rows

Comment: num_rows of any count query will always 1.

Comment: check out the answer

Comment: Getting the `num_rows` property will always be 1. Because you get 1 row back from the query. You need to fetch the data instead of checking the number of rows.

Comment: Additionally, please share the full error message if you receive a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
<?php echo count($this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT destination_name as count FROM mobil")->result_array()); ?>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Since they just want the number of rows, use SQL's `count()` instead of fetching all the rows just to run count() on the result set using PHP.

Comment: Haloo IIIya, this is twice u help me, n your code work!!! thks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php 
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count( distinct destination_name) as cnt FROM mobil");
    $result = $query->row();
    $count = $result->cnt;
    echo $count;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a syntax error here.

```
destination_name_
```

Use this code

```
<?php echo $this->db->query("SELECT count( distinct destination_name) FROM mobil")->num_rows(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct column name for, `destination_name` instead of `destination_name_`.

Accurate query is

```
$this->db->query("SELECT count( distinct destination_name) as cnt FROM mobil");
```

Comment: thks, for your answer @Qirel and kamran geE
but not work

Answer (score 0):

The query is already returns the number of rows, so you just have to echo it :

```php
<?php $q = $this->db->query("SELECT count(distinct destination_name) as dst FROM mobil")->row()->dst; echo !empty($q) ? $q : '0'; ?>
```

Comment: Awesome code,  it's work!!! 
thks @Hasta Dhana